# Iterable of EObject always containing the first object

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

im trying to write a xtend-generator for my xtext-grammar, but always when i try to access to the list elements it only shows the first element and the other elements do not exist. Im confused. Can you help me please?

Here is a code fragment of my grammar:

```
GSockModel:
    '{' 
        gsockItems += GsockItem (';' gsockItems += GsockItem)*
    '}' 
    ;
    

GsockItem:
name=ID '{' 
        (cElt = CElt ';')?
        header = Header ';'
        (options = Options)?
    '}';
```

Here is a code fragment of my generator:

```
class GSockModelGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {

        var items = resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(typeof(GsockItem));


        for (item : items) {
            //always the first get printed here
            println("Item : " + item.name);
        }

    }
}
```

Here a minimal example which worked well

```
{
    asd{

        CElt:{
            type: class;
            name: student;
            serialization: BYTE;
            properties:[
                Name: String;
                Alter: Integer
            ]
        };
        header : {
            connType: UDP;
            serverAddr: 12.45.78.88;
            port: 44;
            maxConn: 1;
            progLang:[ CPP, JAVA];
            os:Lin;
            extName: "asdsa";
            dataType: Ext;
            
        };
        options: {
            output:{
                path : "AS";
                mkdir: No;
            };
        allInOne: Yes
        }

    };
    
asdsa {
        CElt:{
            type: class;
            name: student;
            serialization: BYTE;
            properties:[
                Name: String;
                Alter: Integer
            ]
        };
        header : {
            connType: UDP;
            serverAddr: 12.45.78.88;
            port: 44;
            maxConn: 1;
            progLang:[ CPP, JAVA];
            os:Lin;
            extName: "xd";
            dataType: String;
            
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with the content of the resource? As a side note `toIterable` looks unnecessary to me: `resource.allContents.filter(typeof(GsockItem))`.

Comment: the content of the resouce looked good and when i removed the toIterable  method, as you said, and converted the result to list, it worked. I dont why.
That is how I modified it:



`var items = resource.allContents.filter(typeof(GsockItem)).toList;`

Comment: Please provide more information. How does you sample file and how does your declaration of GsockItem look like?

Comment: @SebastianZarnekow  I updated my question with a minimal version of the grammar, because it is too long to be pasted here and i added a sample too

Comment: Can you confirm that resource.getErrors() returns an empty list?